# Fedora Linux - Bluetooth mouse disconnects after idle time

Tags: linux, fedora, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth laser mouse (ThinkPad) that keeps disconnecting after it has been idle for some time. Once I start moving the mouse again, it pairs automatically and continues working as normal.

This started happening some time ago after a system update. Is this issue related to some IdleTime settings? I looked in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`, but haven't found anything related. Am I missing here something?

I'm running Fedora 27 4.14.14-300. Gnome Bluetooth 3.26.1.

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't a feature of the mouse itself to preserve battery? Does this happen on any other operating systems you've tried?

Comment: It does sound like it would be a feature, but I did not have the possibility to test this on another OS. However, this issue started after an update. I did not have the problem before. Not sure if this "feature" was turned off by default and got activated after the update.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your issue is related to [the new power-saving feature](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/ImprovedLaptopBatteryLife). It is a Fedora 28 feature, but Fedora 27 is also mentioned in "How To Test" section. Here is someone complained it in [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1482649). Following the Bugzilla, I think it may be fixed by changing the auto-suspending setting of the Bluetooth receiver in powertop.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my issue

Type these commands in terminal

```
sudo dnf install powertop

sudo systemctl start powertop.service

sudo systemctl enable powertop.service
```

Then replug your device

If it still doesn't work then open the powertop menu by doing

```
sudo powertop
```

The powertop menu looks like this

> ```
> PowerTOP 2.13 Overview Idle stats Frequency stats Device stats Tunables WakeUp
>
> >> Bad Autosuspend for USB device USB Optical Mouse [Logitech]
>
> Good NMI watchdog should be turned off
>
> Good VM writeback timeout
>
> Good Enable Audio codec power management
>
> Good Bluetooth device interface status
>
> Good Autosuspend for USB device xHCI Host Controller [usb3]
>
> Good Autosuspend for USB device xHCI Host Controller [usb4]
> ```

- Go to Tunables (By pressing Tab)
- Switch Autosuspend for USB device USB Optical Mouse [] to Bad

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I use Microsoft Bluetooth mouse and it has a feature for Low Energy(LE) devices like these. But unfortunately, the same feature fails to make the Bluetooth keyboards work, after idle time, in Fedora 27. A hard solution is to detach and connect back

Comment: You're right. I just looked at the specs and found this: "Advanced power management system automatically switches to low power mode during inactivity". That would explain why it gets inactive. Now the question is, how to turn that off?

Comment: Well, ideally there is no way to turn it off because these are GATT complaint devices which helps in enabling such feature and it helps to save a lot of battery power in the Bluetooth device which is often sought for! Although if you find any way to disable let me know please, here in comment! :)

Comment: Haven't found a solution yet, but there must be a way around it, especially since this started to happen just recently after an update.